# Synonyms for PHP

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I saw that the tag [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) has 15 synonyms, one of which was [php5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php5)... I was wondering why [php7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php7)[php-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7) is not a synonym for php also?

Can someone add php7 as a synonym for php? I think they (php7 & php) are relevant in the same way that php5 is relevant to php.

(Obviously, I don't have the reputation required to make the proposal)

Answer (score 10):

We currently have the following version-specific PHP tags: [php-5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.2) [php-5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.3) [php-5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.4) [php-5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.5) [php-5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.6) [php-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7) [php-7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7.1)

These tags are used (or at least supposed to be used), to ask questions about specific PHP versions, in particular about new features or migration issues. After a time these tags tend to lose their usefulness, because people use them as "this is the version I'm using" tags, even though their question is not limited to a particular version.

I would suggest to:

- Alias [php-5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.2) [php-5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.3) [php-5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.4) [php-5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.5) to [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), as these have outlived their usefulness.
- Rename [php-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7) to [php-7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7.0) to bring it in line with the naming of other tags.

Comment: This seems like the correct thing to do. 5.6 is only supported for one more month, and then is security fixes only for two years. Everything before that is unsupported.

Comment: I think your suggestion is better than my own. I just thought something seemed off about the php tags. I realize, I seem to have stumbled upon a great subject here, and hope the discussion leads to a good outcome.

Comment: It also could be just [tag:php-5] or [tag:php-5.x]